# Get current directory in erlang

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I'm using `chicagoboss` for web development. To test some test modules I would like to change my current directory to something else. I know I can change directory by specifying full path to to `cd("full path")`. 
Suppose I'm in a directory "/home/user/workspace/myproject/myapp/" where I'm running myproject project.But now I want to check  my current location using erlang shell.

Is there any function/command in `erlang` to get current working directory? In python I was using `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: You may have better success in the long run if you look up `priv_dirs`. Each application in Erlang has a private directory for static data. Highly useful in some cases, though it is not directly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

`{ok, CurrentDirectory} = file:get_cwd()`.

Also check out [erldocs.com](http://erldocs.com) to quickly look up functions in the Erlang documentation.

Answer (score 7):

Use the command:

```
pwd().
```

More text to get to the Stackoverflow minimum

Comment: Note that this prints out the directory and returns `ok`